# Freeware alternative to Total Commander on Windows x64?

Tags: file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free alternative to Total Commander](https://superuser.com/questions/38951/free-alternative-to-total-commander)

Which tool could replace total commander on x64 based windows systems?

Total Commander does not handle copying of huge amounts of files from one drive to another. Windows is making this a lot of faster. Do you know any similar program that I could use instead of it? It has to be the same functionality.

I have to be able to install this legally on corporation computer.

Comment: You could have started with "Is there a way to make Total Commander file copying faster"; unless you researched it, of course.

Comment: Have you checked [these](http://superuser.com/questions/38951/free-alternative-to-total-commander)?